# Public beta has started

Tags: discussion, promotion, beta

<s>According to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games), we're entering Public Beta in less than a day.</s> **Public beta has started!**

We should be ready for this, and prepared to take advantage of the increased opportunities for exposure. We should also be careful not to spam other forums too much, or we may irritate people and make them less disposed to be interested in BCG.SE.

I think a good rule of thumb is to try and make sure we only announce the public beta once in any given forum, and perhaps announce it again once it goes out of beta. So please, before posting about BCG.SE in a particular forum, check to see if someone already has; try not to be too spammy.

Beyond that, we should focus on trying to publicize the BCG.SE by providing links to great questions and answers when we see related topics come up in other forums. If you have a rules dispute with a friend, link them to a question on it here. If someone asks a question on BGG, and there's a good answer here, link to that. If you copy the link directly from the "link" that you see under the tags (right click it and choose "Copy Link Address" or something similar), then the number of people you refer will even be counted, and you can get a badge for helping to publicize a question.

An obvious place to mention BCG.SE is BoardGameGeek, and it might be good if you have a personal blog, twitter feed, Facebook account, or the like, to mention that you've been involved in a private beta of a board game Q&A site that is now entering it's public beta. I haven't been as actively involved in the online board gaming community recently, so I'm not sure who all people are reading or listening to these days, but it might be good to see if we can contact Tom Vasel and have him mention BCG.SE on The Dice Tower, as that's pertty popular among gamers. Again, we should try not to be to contact any one person or forum too excessively, but make sure that we get our name out there to a few important places.

Any other thoughts on how we should publicize BCG.SE, without spamming? Thoughts on where we should publicize it?

Comment: Anybody have any ins with the guys over at Penny Arcade? :D

Answer (score 11):

As always, we feel the best and easiest way to promote your site is to **share links to great questions and answers**, like so:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

Answer (score 7):

Email.

Other than SO and here, I have absolutely 0 web presence anymore -- no Facebook, no Twitter, no more LJ, nothing.  It makes it a little hard for me to publicize anything :)

That said, while it's not *public*, I e-mailed a few people about the site when it was in the commitment phase, and I'll be e-mailing them again, plus anyone else I can think of that has any interest in board games, and try to get them over here.

There are roughly 200 users right now -- if each of us e-mailed 10 people we knew, and even only one person per user here signs up as a result, that's still 200 new users, who know other people, who know other people...

Comment: This. You stole my answer! :) Everyone knows who their board game savvy friends are and knows them personally, so contacting them is going to be _even more_ effective than a message on a blog or a forum. +1.

Answer (score 5):

Drop a link to the site in your signature in any game related forum you frequent.  Use your [flair](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/flair) for bonus points!

Answer (score 4):

If you are a member of a game club, or if you visit game conventions, drop the link as often as possible.